# Overstayer in UK wants to go to Germany

Tags: visas, air-travel, international-travel

I am an overstayer in the UK and have been here for a couple of years. I know would like to visit Germany before I go back home to Brazil. Would German border control stop me or allow entry for 90 days? My German girlfriend would travel with me should that help if they question me?

Or, what would happen if I return to Brazil and fly from Brazil to Germany? Would that give me a better chance of visiting?

Comment: How do you plan to convince them that you will leave by the end of the 90 days given your history in the UK?

Comment: I would show proof of my return flight to Brazil

Comment: Did you do that when you entered the UK? You may need to prove a more compelling tie to Brazil than a flight that can be easily changed or even abandoned

Comment: A return ticket is proof of nothing more than the fact you bought a return ticket.  It doesn't prove in any way that you actually plan to take that flight.

Comment: A return ticket is not proof you intend to leave, true. In fact, a refundable ticket is a ploy  some use when they haven’t decided how long they want to stay.  But even though it isn’t proof, the ploy often works.

Comment: How serious is this girlfriend we are talking about here? are we talking someone you intend to marry?

Comment: Yes, we have been together three years and we would like to get married in Brazil next year.

Answer (score 7):

Nobody can definitively predict what will happen in a situation like this, however...

As a Brazilian citizen you do not require a visa for a short-stay in Germany.  Coming from the UK, you are currently allowed enter Germany under their COVID-19 rules (although this could change at any time).  So based on that it is most likely that you would be allow board the flight to Germany.

Thus whether you are allowed entry Germany will come down to the immigration staff at the airport where you land.

Almost certainly, if they discover that you have overstayed in the UK then you will be denied entry - on the very simple grounds that you have shown a tendency to not abide by the rules in the past, so they will presume that you are likely to also overstay in Germany.

Whether they discover your overstay will depend.  The UK does not generally have outbound (physical) immigration checks, so your passport will not be marked as being an overstayer like it might otherwise be for some other countries.  Under normal circumstances it's possible the German immigration staff may not notice the overstay and you might be allowed in - but we are not living in normal circumstances at the moment.

The immigration staff will almost certainly want to be aware of your recent travel history, and that will mean looking through your passport - at which point they will discover your overstay, and as mentioned above that will almost certainly result in you being denied entry.

Once you are denied entry you will be in a very bad spot.  Normally you would be returned to your origin, but given the UK will not accept you, that won't be possible.  Most likely you will be forced to travel directly to Brazil - which will happen at your cost.

Having your German girlfriend with you will only make matters worse, as (in their eyes) it increases the odds that you are planning to relocate to German with her, and thus planning to overstay your allowed 90 day stay.

Again, nobody can be sure exactly what will happen, but your odds of being able to pull this off are extremely small.

Comment: What in your opinion would happen if I return to Brazil and visit Germany flying from Brazil to Germany? Would that again raise the same questions or give me a better chance of visiting?

Comment: Comments shouldn’t be used for new questions.  Usually, a separate question should be posted.  However, in this case, it seemed better to add this to the original question.

Comment: @ATK Entry to Germany is not currently allow from Brazil due to COVID-19 restrictions.

Comment: Thank you but let’s pretend COVID is not the issue :-)

Comment: @ATK, if you wait until COVID is *no longer* an issue, your situation might look different. You would have been in Brazil for quite some time.

Comment: "at which point they will discover your overstay": how?  The UK does not have exit stamps.  I doubt they'd notice, frankly.  Furthermore, a tendency not to abide by the rules is not sufficient grounds for refusal of entry.  They need a specific reason.

Comment: @phoog They will see an entry stamp to the UK with an expiry several years earlier, and nothing more recent.  Unless the OP plans on lying about their travel history (which will be undefinable) then it'll be pretty clear what has happened.